# Overflowing the viewport

Tags: html, css

Can anyone explain me on how the below fiddle is `overflowing the viewport`.

```
.row > .sidebar-fixed{
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.row > .sidebar-fixed.left{
    left:0;
}
.row > .sidebar-fixed.right{
    right:0;
}

.fixed-fixed {
    margin: 0 240px;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/X0Bie7aRN0

When specifying or hardcoding some `top value`, why should the `height not be 100%` and `bottom be 0`

```
  .row > .sidebar-fixed{
        position: absolute;
        top: 60px;
        width: 220px;
        height: 100%; // should replaced by bottom: 0;
        overflow-y:scroll;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Height's percentage values are relative to the element's [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#containing).

Provided your absolutely positioned element does not have any positioned ancestor (with `position` different than `static`), its containing block will be the [initial containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#initial), in that case `100%` height computes to the height of the viewport.

When you have defined a `height` property, without a `bottom` property, the `top` property will simply offset the element's position, but will not alter its defined height.

`bottom:0` aligns the element's margin-box's bottom edge with the containing block's padding-box's bottom edge. ([ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#bottom), [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D59na/))

And to demonstrate the initial containing block, heights and positioning behavior, see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J79g6/4/).

Comment: Excellent example... when I remove the height: 100% and replace it with bottom: 0... I don't see the scrollbar on right side anymore. http://www.bootply.com/tzJNs9jXU1 the overall scrollbar which comes because of the height.

Answer (score 1):

What is so surprising? `height: 100%` means setting an element height to 100% of its parent IF the parent height is specified too. Then, you set its position to 60px from top, but it doesn't change an element height at all. So it's quite natural that its bottom edge is 60px below a viewport.

As for `bottom: 0`, when you specify `top` property - element's top edge is placed at a specified height relative to the top edge of its parent with `position: relative|absolute`. When you specify `bottom` property, element's bottom edge is placed at a specified height of its parent with `position: absolute|relative`. Specifying both these properties at once lead to stretching the element. This is actually quite a common way of specifying an element height.

Comment: "IF the parent height is specified too." -- absolutely positioned elements do not have that restriction.

Comment: Actually they do, but a `parent` is a bit different for these elements.

Comment: Should I remove the height: 100% and replace with bottom: 0 or should I keep top, height and bottom.

Comment: @Twi Try it out man. The reason for height % values requiring a set parent height is because the parent's `height:auto` would not be able to be computed. Absolutely positioned elements are not part of the parent's height computation, so the restriction does not apply. This is CSS 101.

Comment: @Shane there's no reason to keep the `height`, unless you want a fallback to IE5 or so which did not support defining both `top` and `bottom` properties on the same element.

Comment: If you don't want an overflow then `bottom: 0` is your best bet. Also, you should really look into `flexboxes` for this kind of layout.

Comment: when I remove the height: 100% and replace it with bottom: 0... I don't see the scrollbar on right side anymore. bootply.com/tzJNs9jXU1 the overall scrollbar which comes because of the height.